# Never ending vercel launch of my firebase project

Tags: firebase, hosting, web-hosting, netlify, vercel

My firebase project has been working perfectly fine. The problem arises as it took me ages to launch the project on vercel and netlify. What are some common issues within it as I cannot import all of the codes

I refreshes my browser, restarted my computer, uploaded my repo on github again....nothing seems to work

This is the result of the vercel building part

```
[23:23:56.333] Cloning github.com/dunyanong/Feedback-Form (Branch: main, Commit: 368a226)
[23:23:58.531] Cloning completed: 2.198s
[23:24:00.965] Looking up build cache...
[23:24:01.269] Build Cache not found
[23:24:01.382] Running "vercel build"
[23:24:02.031] Vercel CLI 28.2.2
[23:24:02.361] Installing dependencies...
[23:24:03.384] 
[23:24:03.384] up to date in 768ms
[23:24:03.384] 
[23:24:03.385] 19 packages are looking for funding
[23:24:03.385]   run `npm fund` for details
[23:24:03.401] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[23:24:03.401] Running "npm run build"
[23:24:03.787] 
[23:24:03.787] > login-form@1.0.0 build
[23:24:03.787] > webpack
[23:24:03.788] 
[23:24:05.262] asset bundle.js 1010 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main)
[23:24:05.262] runtime modules 891 bytes 4 modules
[23:24:05.262] modules by path ./node_modules/ 937 KiB
[23:24:05.262]   modules by path ./node_modules/@firebase/ 926 KiB
[23:24:05.263]     ./node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js 32.6 KiB [built] [code generated]
[23:24:05.263]     ./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js 760 KiB [built] [code generated]
[23:24:05.263]     ./node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js 16.5 KiB [built] [code generated]
[23:24:05.263]     ./node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.esm2017.js 66.1 KiB [built] [code generated]
[23:24:05.263]     + 2 modules
[23:24:05.264]   modules by path ./node_modules/firebase/ 901 bytes
[23:24:05.264]     ./node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.esm.js 826 bytes [built] [code generated]
[23:24:05.264]     ./node_modules/firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm.js 75 bytes [built] [code generated]
[23:24:05.264]     ./node_modules/idb/build/index.js 3.09 KiB [built] [code generated]
[23:24:05.264]     ./node_modules/idb/build/wrap-idb-value.js 7.32 KiB [built] [code generated]
[23:24:05.265] ./src/index.js 1.44 KiB [built] [code generated]
[23:24:05.265] webpack 5.74.0 compiled successfully in 976 ms
```

Comment: When I had similar problem, it turned out to be dependencies issues. Specifically, I had to move `next` and `react` and others from `dev_dependencies` to `dependencies`. Do that, rebuild and then check if that resolves your issue.

Comment: @PeterObiechina , my project is not a next or react project, it is just purely vanilla js and while the backend is connected to firebase